# RabbitMQ message retry mechanism

Tags: rabbitmq, rmq

I am trying to implement re-produce logic:

1. when a message fails, it should be routed to a dead letter queue (DLQ). After a delay of 5 seconds, the message should automatically return to the main queue for reprocessing.
2. this retry mechanism should occur a maximum of 5 times. If the message fails more than 5 times, it should then be redirected to a separate queue dedicated to manual review.

The first part I have already solved but need assistance with the second one. Please note: I'd like to implement within the RabbitMQ level, NOT consumer.